# Android - Why is my image view taking up most of the screen? I want it to take up all the space beneath the custom app bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager

So as you can see from the image the imageView slideshow picture of space is taking up nearly the entire screen when I want it to:

1. Start beneath the action bar (You can see the lighter purple colour of custom app bar)
2. Take up all the space beneath this.
   If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it greatly, thanks.
   Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joh9j.jpg

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextColor"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/TextColor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"


        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <!-- viewpager to show images -->
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: Is your ImageView in ViewPager? If yes, please add this to your view pager layout 
**android : layout_below ="@id/app_bar_layout"**

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your Parent Layout(Relative Layout as well) .
I think it has not been properly constrained. Set your parent Relative layout height to match the parent.

Also set `android:layout_alignParentTop="false"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from the ViewPager, and replace it with `android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"`

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/TextColor"
     android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout" >

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         style="@style/TextColor"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"


     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


     <!-- viewpager to show images -->
     <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/viewPagerMain"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```